# Regex remove everything after <

Tags: regex

I have a string that looks like:

```
 some text <a some text "quote" slash..
```

I want to remove everything after the `<` so the above string will result in:

```
some text
```

How do I do that? Do i need to use a regex for that?

Comment: It seems your question lost some of the characters, try putting "some text" in a code block

Comment: Do the `<strong>` and `</strong>` tags belong to your string or are they due to wrong formatting?

Comment: RegEx sounds overkilling for this task.

Answer (score 1):

`<[^<]+> [^<]*(?<removeGroup><[^<]*)<[^<]+>`
 use this regular expression to match and  remove unwanted string by using the 'removeGroup' in the match.(in .net)

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple so you don't even need to use regex to do this. You can just use string methods, here's a quick write up in C#:

```
string str = "some text <a some text \"quote\" slash..";
int index = str.IndexOf("<");
string newstr = str.Substring(0, index);

Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", newstr);  // prints 'some text '
```